# Can I call a model function using the URL (without using routes)? CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

It is my understanding that, by default, Codeigniter user this patter to access functions.

`http://domain.tdl/controller/model`

can this be done by default without having to edit the routes?

Comment: Actually, by default it is `controller/method/params`. Anyway, as long as the mapping is right, you don't need routes

Comment: Damien Pirsy gave the answer. Plus you'll need to read the documentation, there is some great stuff in the static pages section:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in codeigniter because of it's MVC architecture so better to use model with   it's regular flow.

Comment: codigniter's architecture has **nothing** to do with MVC

Comment: Maybe he meant the work flow pattern where u cannot jump directly to the data entity unless through the model which by right will be accessed via the controller.